# Objective C, How to make the corner of a picture in UIImageView round?

Tags: objective-c

[image]

I want to do something like that..
How to make the corner of the image in the UIImageview round?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you:

```
CALayer *l = [<yourimageview> layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to make any size UIImageView round.

UIImageView *img = [ [UIImageView alloc]init ];

Img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.size.width / 2;

[Img.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

thank you .
Happy coding